# Android AutoCompleteTextView : Perform a AsyncTask call only once on TextChange

Tags: android, android-asynctask, autocomplete

I have an AutoCompleteTextView in my layout. After the user entered the first character, I'd like to do an API call, which I'm doing in an AsyncTask. I've used addTextChangedListener and I'm doing the API call on TextChanged. But the problem is that the API call is getting done each time the user makes any change to the AutoCompleteTextView.

But I'd want the API call to happen only once, that is after the first character is inputted. How do I achieve this ?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_places_search);
    search_airport = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.place_search);
    autocompleteadapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, airports);
    search_airport.setAdapter(autocompleteadapter);
    search_airport.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mAirport = new AsyncTaskAirport(search_airport.getEditableText().toString().substring(0, 1));
            mAirport.execute((Void) null);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }
    });


}
```

Comment: What if the user enters a character, then deletes it, then enters another character?  What if the user enters a character, then backs up to the first position and inserts another character before the first one?

Comment: @DougStevenson Yeah...I'll have to consider those cases also.. Can you tell how I can achieve all these scenarios ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if(s.toString().trim().length()==1){
       mAirport = new AsyncTaskAirport(search_airport.getEditableText().toString().substring(0, 1));
       mAirport.execute((Void) null);
     }

 }
```

Comment: Facepalm. Thanks. Elegant and simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem with a timer.Here is how

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
{
    int COMPLETION_DELAY = 2000;
    if (timer != null)
    {
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        timer = null;
    }
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if (s.toString().length() >= appCompatAutoCompleteTextView.getThreshold())
                    {
                         //CALL WebService Here
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, COMPLETION_DELAY);
}
```

now your service will not be called when user making changes while typing in auto complete. service will only be called once user stops + 2 Second.